# Update/Change custom TaxonomyFieldValue in document library list in sharepoint using C# CSOM

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, custom-taxonomy, sharepointdocumentlibrary, taxonomy-terms

list of documents thats contains custom taxonomy field column named subject.
Need to update subject of thousands records/documents.
Please any idea to update the taxonomy field such subject programtically using C# CSOM

Comment: what have you tried? show us some code.

Comment: thanks, i solved the problem

Answer (score 2):

Please try to use this method:

```
public void UpdateTaxonomyField(ClientContext ctx, List list,ListItem listItem,string fieldName,string fieldValue)
        {
            Field field = list.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle(fieldName);
            TaxonomyField txField = clientContext.CastTo<TaxonomyField>(field);
            TaxonomyFieldValue termValue = new TaxonomyFieldValue();
            string[] term = fieldValue.Split('|');
            termValue.Label = term[0];
            termValue.TermGuid = term[1];
            termValue.WssId = -1;
            txField.SetFieldValueByValue(listItem, termValue);
            listItem.Update();
            ctx.Load(listItem);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   public static void UpdateListofLibraryHavingTaxonomyField()
    {
        string siteUrl = "http://abc:55555/sites/xyz/";
        string libName = "Knowledge Repos";
        string strTermGuid = "Your new/update term guid";
        try
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> dictIdsSubjectsChange = ReadFromExcel();//Here to read all records (approx 2000 records) that we want to change
            ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
            List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(libName);
            FieldCollection fields = list.Fields;
            Field field = fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle("Subject1");
            ListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());
            clientContext.Load(listItems, items => items.Include(i => i["Subject1"], i => i["ID"]));
            clientContext.Load(fields);
            clientContext.Load(field);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            TaxonomyField txField = clientContext.CastTo<TaxonomyField>(field);               
            TaxonomyFieldValue termValue = null;
            if (dictIdsSubjectsChange != null)
            {
                foreach (ListItem listItem in listItems)//Loop through all items of the document library 
                {
                    string strCurrentID = "0";
                    try
                    {
                        strCurrentID = listItem["ID"].ToString();
                    }
                    catch (Exception) { }                      
                    if (dictIdsSubjectsChange.ContainsKey(strCurrentID))//Checking to change ot not
                    {
                        termValue = new TaxonomyFieldValue();
                        termValue.Label = "Special Knowledge";
                        termValue.TermGuid = strTermGuid;
                        termValue.WssId = 246;
                        txField.SetFieldValueByValue(listItem, termValue);
                        listItem.Update();
                        clientContext.Load(listItem);
                    }
                }
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }
    }
}
```